# Firebase - TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

I am just starting up with firebase.

i am not sure ins and out of the firebase and based on my vaguely understanding, I have configured my app this way.

In the main **Index.js** file, I am requiring

```
const path = require('path')
const firebaseConfig = require("./src/config/firebaseConfig.js")
const firebaseDb = require("./src/helperFunctions/firebase_db.js")
```

Here, firebaseConfig is the place where I am configuring my firebase

```
const firebaseConfigJSON = require("./functions-config.json")
const admin = require("firebase-admin");


admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseConfigJSON),
    databaseURL: "https://functions-firebase-43a59.firebaseio.com"
})

const db =  admin.firestore()
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

 module.exports = {
    db
 }
```

and then using this imported Db in `firebaseDb`

```
//All the operations at firebase store would be done from here 
const firebaseDb = require("./../config/firebaseConfig.js")

    firebaseDb.db.collection('users').add({
        name: "Rohit Bhatia",
        age: "24"
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("this is response", response)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("This is error in firebase", err)
    })
```

Since most of the code is singleton here, I was expecting everything to go smoothly until I received following error

> This is error in firebase TypeError: Path must be a string. Received
>   undefined
>
> at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
>
> at Object.join (path.js:1236:7)
>
> at getPath (/Users/anilbhatia/Desktop/google-functions/functions/node_modules/dir-glob/index.js:6:41)
>
> at globs.concat.map.x (/Users/anilbhatia/Desktop/google-functions/functions/node_modules/dir-glob/index.js:47:59)
>
> at Array.map ()
>
> at module.exports.sync (/Users/anilbhatia/Desktop/google-functions/functions/node_modules/dir-glob/index.js:47:33)
>
> at globDirs (/Users/anilbhatia/Desktop/google-functions/functions/node_modules/globby/index.js:58:9)
>
> at getPattern (/Users/anilbhatia/Desktop/google-functions/functions/node_modules/globby/index.js:61:64)
>
> at globTasks.reduce (/Users/anilbhatia/Desktop/google-functions/functions/node_modules/globby/index.js:107:19)
>    at Array.reduce ()

Can someone please help me in figuring out what could I be doing wrong? or perhaps did I actually got the firebase?

My initial goal was to create a collection in my firebase via my express app before putting data from api routes.

Comment: Starting today I also received this error at locations where 'path' cannot be undefined. Looking forward to some explanations

Comment: The dir-glob package was updated today (2.2.0), and it seems to be breaking things. (firebase, among other things)

Comment: even I started getting this error on firebase deployed environment, not able reproduce this on local.

Comment: same error here since last deploy few mins ago

Comment: run `npm update` inside `'functions` directory and deploy. This updated all packages. This fixed for me.

Comment: `npm update` didn't fixed the error for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to revert the `dir-glob` to 2.0.0 by adding:

```
"dir-glob": "2.0.0",
"globby": "8.0.0",
```

In the package.json `dependencies`.

You can do this with:

```
npm install dir-glob@2.0.0 --save
npm install globby@8.0.0 --save
```

We then deleted the `node_modules` and run: `npm install` and deployed to Firebase

Answer (score 3):

Try running:
`npm install firebase-admin@6.4.0`

Also you can do:
`npm install`
`npm run build` (inside functions folder.)

Then `firebase deploy`.

Fixed it for me.

Comment: What was the reason then, I wasn't able to reproduce this on local environment?

Comment: Local environment worked fine regardless, I think it's the update of that dir-gob package causing issues for people like this guy, and me. Personally we hadn't updated firebaseadmin (or anything) since the start, but after doing so, no issues on live or local.

Comment: updating firebase-admin fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

**Future googler's**

Make sure in your `firebase.json` file you have the correct `source` path:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "source": "."
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue - but my only reference to source in firebase.json is: "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]